# Back button of Google Chrome after clicking a hyperlink whose target is on the same PDF document

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts, url-parameters

PDF documents have hyperlinks to the contents on the same document (analogous to "#section" hrefs for an HTML document). Where's the back button to go back to the page I was on (where I clicked the hyperlink).

Let's say I'm on the index of a PDF tutorial, page 4, and I click on Chapter 2's hyperlink in the index that takes me to page 38. Now, if I want to go back to page 4 again, which button or shortcut should I use?

Within all browsers, excpet Google Chrome, you can press Alt and the left arrow to achieve this. Is there a similar shortcut within Google Chrome?

Comment: Strange: The title and first two paragraphs of this question are verbatim from https://superuser.com/questions/22786/back-button-of-adobe-pdf-reader-after-clicking-a-hyperlink-whose-target-is-on-th

Comment: Firefox 62 can do it BTW, it is the best Linux PDF reader as of 2018 IMHO: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/what-pdf-viewers-are-available-for-ubuntu/1085859#1085859

Comment: can't believe chrome doesn't have this function yet as of 2019. March!

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK there is no way to do it with the standard Chrome PDF Viewer. Take a look at their support page https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1060734. You could try requesting this feature but keep in mind that the PDF viewer is part of Chrome, not Chromium.

Answer (score 4):

While the builtin pdf reader in Chrome does not support `Alt + Left` you can use [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=en), to replace the pdf reader with one that supports the `Alt + Left` functionality that you desire. Moreover, when using this extension, if you press the back button on chrome's address bar it takes you back to the previous view.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is awesome! It works magically. Thanks, @AHK!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler to just open the hyperlink in a new tab *e.g.* with the middle mouse button. Then you can just close the tab afterwards.

Answer (score -7):

Alt + Left should be what you want.

Comment: Not in Chrome. i just tested it again.

Comment: What os you have, I use chrome in my ubuntu and it really works here.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise Edition. That explains it.

Comment: Alt + Left appears to simply be a shortcut for the browser's back button - which takes you *out* of the pdf.  We need to go back to the hyperlink source location *within* the pdf.